# Specify default template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Assume I have a template function like:

```
template<typename T, typename DType=uint32_t>
void fun(T a) {
    //...
    // DType is used inside
}
```

How can I specify the type of `DType`, but let `T` be deduced by the compiler, something like:

```
fun<DType=int32_t>(static_cast<std::string>(s));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you wrote it you cannot. Your best bet is to interchange the types and let the compiler deduce the type for `T`, like

```
template<typename DType=uint32_t, typename T>
void fun(T a) {
    //...
    // DType is used inside
}
```

The compiler will deduce the type of `T` accordingly.

Example

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename DType = uint32_t, typename T>
void fun(T a) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    fun<char>(42); // T is deduced as int, DType as char
}
```

As mentioned by @T.C. in the comments: *"There's no requirement that default template arguments for function templates be on trailing template parameters, unlike class templates."*

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/015804fa9fca295f)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Thanks! It never occurred to me before I saw this question that we can actually do this!

Comment: You don't need that default. The language isn't insane.

Comment: @T.C How do you specify then a non-default type for `DType`?

Comment: `template<typename DType = uint32_t, typename T> void fun(T);` There's no requirement that default template arguments for function templates be on trailing template parameters, unlike class templates.

Comment: @T.C. You're right, edited, I was mistakenly thinking the same rule apply as for class templates, as you mentioned.

Comment: @T.C. Now that C++17 has class type deduction via the ctor, will we be able to do the same thing with classes? I.e., non-trailing default type parameters?

Comment: No, the rules haven't changed. I'm not sure I see a use case for that, given that with class templates you can't have "specify some and deduce the rest".

Answer (score 0):

The best I can imagine is add a `DType` unused argument

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename DType = uint32_t>
void fun(T a, DType = 0) {
    //...
    // DType is used inside
}

int main ()
 {
   char s[] = "abc";

   fun(static_cast<std::string>(s));
   fun(static_cast<std::string>(s), int32_t{0});
 }
```

Obviously this work only for some `DTypes`; by example, if `DType` is fixed to `void`

```
fun<std::string, void>(static_cast<std::string>(s));
```

you get a compilation error.